# Convert list to ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, xamarin

i need to convert my list which i get from an api call, to a ObservableCollection to put into my graph.

i tried these 2 methods:

method1:

```
ObservableCollection<ChartDataModel> test = new ObservableCollection<ChartDataModel>(_CoinHistoryGraph as List<CoinHistoryModel>);
```

error on method 1:

```
cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<CoinMarketCap.SHARED.Models.CoinHistoryModel>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<CoinMarketCap.SHARED.ViewModels.ChartDataModel>'    CoinMarketCap.SHARED
```

Method2:

```
CoinHistory = _CoinHistoryGraph.Select(x => new ChartDataModel(float.Parse(x.price_btc), double.Parse(x.timestamp)));
```

error on method2:

```
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<CoinMarketCap.SHARED.ViewModels.ChartDataModel>' to 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<CoinMarketCap.SHARED.ViewModels.ChartDataModel>'.
```

Models:

```
 public class GraphModel
{
    public GraphModel(float pricebtc, double time_stamp)
    {
        price_btc = pricebtc;
        timestamp = time_stamp;
    }

    public float price_btc { get; set; }
    public double timestamp { get; set; }
}

  public class CoinHistoryModel
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string price_btc { get; set; }
    public string timestamp { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Try passing your `Select` result to the `ObservableCollection` constructor instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create an ObservableCollection from a List of CoinHistoryModel, it's better to use this code:

```
CoinHistory = new ObservableCollection<ChartDataModel>(_CoinHistoryGraph.Select(x => new ChartDataModel(float.Parse(x.price_btc), double.Parse(x.timestamp))));
```

Your first piece of code doesn't work because you want to create an ObservableCollection of ChartDataModel type from the collection of CoinHistoryModel type. 
And about your second piece of code, the error message is clear enough. You want to explicitly cast IEnumerable object to ObservableCollection one.
To creating an ObservableCollection of type1 from a collection of type1, you can pass the collection as the ObservableCollection first constructor parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Your generic parameter in `new ObservableCollection<T>` needs to match the generic parameter of the `IEnumerable<T>` or `List<T>` you pass into the constructor. So you need to pass in a `List<ChartDataModel>`, not `List<GraphModel>` or `List<CoinHistoryModel>`.